# After update, Ubuntu booting into black screen (but ssh working)

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, aptitude

I am running Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS on HP ProLiant server.

After recent update (using apt-get update and upgrade), it boots into black screen. BIOS Post screen still shows normally, but when the OS takes over the monitor, I get only black screen. It is working, I can connect to it through SSH from my windows notebook. At first I have tried to solve the problem myself using google, but nothing worked as expected and I am afraid I did more bad then good.

I kept all things done since problem started written in notepad on win. machine, but lost it all on forced restart by windows update. As far as I remember, I tried modifying grub config to boot with options "quiet splash nomodeset" and then I tried several ways to reinstall graphic drivers or xorg.

Tell me if you need to see any configs or logs (path including).

**edit** : I reinstalled the server in the end.

Comment: You're more likely to get help here if you state a specific question. For example, "Why doesn't the display awake from sleep when I press enter?" or, "Why isn't my web server running, even though I can connect via ssh?"

Comment: Are you watching this via a remote KVM or do you have local access to the server? Did you try to add "vga=normal" to your boot options?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem a month ago. With Ubuntu 12.04. BIOS was displayed normally.

On HP Proliant DL 3xx you have 2 VGA port. One on the front side and an other on the back side.

I used the back side VGA port. And when I simply connected the cable on the front side instead of the back one, it worked. :)

Answer (score 1):

Hey this may be a little late....but I had the exact same problem and solved it with this shortcut!

https://askubuntu.com/questions/66195/what-is-a-tty-and-how-do-i-access-a-tty

as soon as I pressed it it opened up a shell for me (mind you I am running ubuntu server and not desktop so you might want to use the "7" option)